# MSTeams dev: Navigate from Personal tab to different Team/conversation

Tags: microsoft-teams

**Question**

How can I create a link to navigate to a Team's channel, from within a custom *personal tab*?

**Context**

I'm trying to navigate from within a *personal tab* to a Team the user is a member of. I've tried the only 2 options I can think of so far:

- using an `a` tag
- using `microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink`

But they don't work.

- When clicking the `a` tag, the *tab contents* are redirect to the general MS Teams navigation page, where you can choose to open in client or web.
- When using the `microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink` function, a result is returned containing the error message `The executeDeepLink API is not implemented in this client`.

It seems the API only works on *team (configurable) tabs* on the desktop client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nsevens This feature is not public yet. Could you please try this in the [Developer Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro)

Comment: Thank you @gousia-msft. I can enable the developer preview, but I don't have all documentation to build the complete link. Is there any info you can share how to create the link exactly? Or what URL would be the correct one to use as a deep link?

Comment: @Nsevens Please go through [deep linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links).

Comment: I can see a lot of scenarios there: link to "your tab", a chat, scheduling dialog. However, since we want to provide a deep link to for example the "Conversations" tab of a Team I am a member of, there is no appId, no entityId I know, no entityWebUrl, etc...

Comment: You can copy the link to the channel of the Team by clicking on the Menu and choose [Get link to channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hdga.png). You can do the same thing for any tab on that channel.

Comment: this seems to work, but only in the MS Teams desktop client. The web client returns the mentioned error message. Is this something that is yet to be implemented?

Comment: @Nsevens as discussed this feature is still in developer preview. Could you please confirm if you are trying this in developer preview. Because it works for me in devpreview both in desktop and web client.

Comment: Yes, I enabled dev preview. desktop client works, web client doesn't. Not sure what I'm doing wrong then... (code I use is: `microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3a5c6b6fa2082148bcb357c6605381b6bc%40thread.skype/General?groupId=718cc12f-c623-4071-b4c0-327a1b0e6239&tenantId=8b3aae36-45af-473c-8707-31692e7ac784");`

Comment: Can you try it this way
microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink('https://teams.microsoft.com/l/team/19%3a065336afb43c4343b7042e1c55b09353%40thread.skype/conversations?groupId=b0edb996-dd5e-413b-b5bd-fbc961e69a9f&tenantId=72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47')

Comment: Same issue in the web client. In the desktop client this then opens a web browser showing "Bad Request", also might be worth mentioning: I'm currently referencing @microsoft/teams-js 1.5.0-beta.2
ps: thank you for your help on this :)

Comment: the web client was my bad. I didn't know that enabling developer preview was client-specific. I had only enabled it in the desktop client. Deeplink seems to work as it should now. Thank you for the assistance!